# How we can find GCD(k + a, k + b) if we already know the GCD(a, b)?

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, euclidean-algorithm

I was wondering if its possible in constant time to calculate the above mentioned goal. I need it to solve a problem on codechef.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a mathematics question, and as such belongs on the Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: @gspr How to compute something in constant time (if possible) is a question relevant to programming. The boundary between mathematics and computer science isn't sharp.

Comment: @JohnColeman: I agree that the line between mathematics and CS is fuzzy. It is definitely an open question as to whether this question best fits the math or the CS stack exchanges, but I don't see how it belongs on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to compute `gcd(a+k,b+k)` in constant time knowing only `gcd(a,b)`.

Suppose that `c,d` are any two natural numbers with `d < c`.

Let

```
a = d - d = 0
b = c - d
k = d
```

Then we know in `O(1)` time that

```
gcd(a,b) = gcd(0, c - d) = c - d
```

If we could compute `gcd(a+k,b+k) = gcd(c,d)` in `O(1)` additional time, then we could compute *all* gcds in `O(1)` time, which is impossible.

Having said all that, it is of course possible that in some cases of interest, knowledge of `gcd(a,b)` could lead to faster computation of `gcd(a+k,b+k)` than would otherwise be possible.